# jquery keep checking if input is empty of not

Tags: jquery

I want to check if the input is empty or not **while the user is typing**

this is my code

```
$('#visitID').on('change', function () {
        if ($('#visitID').val().length == 0) {
            $("#saveandclosebutton").hide();
        } else {
            $("#saveandclosebutton").show();
        }
    });
```

but the `saveandclosebutton` never becomes hidden even though if my input is empty.

Comment: try `keypress`/`keyup` events because now your code will fire only when the input loses its focus after changing the value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind the event handler to both the `keyup` and `change` events, but you also want to cause the event handler to get executed when the page loads:

```
$('#visitID').on('keyup change', function() {
    $('#saveandclosebutton').toggle($(this).val().length > 0);
}).change();
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/29DSq/)

Comment: The first code you provided was better except that it shows the button when the input is empty and hide the button when the input is fill. your code now is hide then show then hide then show with each new input

Comment: @user2226785 - The issue was that the argument to the `.toggle()` method must be a boolean. I have edited my answer to fix the code.

Answer (score 3):

You could include checking on `keyup` as well, e.g:

```
$('#visitID').on('change keyup', function () {
  this.value ? $("#saveandclosebutton").show() : $("#saveandclosebutton").hide();
});
```

[**jsFiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/b2XmK/3/)

Of course you'd need to set the button to be `display:none` initally, as your `<input>` would originally be empty.

```
#saveandclosebutton {
   display:none;
}
```

Comment: still the button is always shows. could you give an jidffl example ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that guy has helped me first. I wish I could accept more than one answer, +1 to your efforts with me. you great

Answer (score 1):

I guess that the `saveandclosebutton` is called differently. Try first to see if the main logic is working at all:

```
$('#visitID').on('change keyup', function () {
      console.log($('#visitID').val().length);
});
```

and check if the console has any output at all. You can add the `keyup` as I did so that the check is done after each keypress.

Comment: Do you imply that the script is not being called? I have 45 other scripts on that file and all are working. So, I guess the function is executed.

Comment: Well, no need to feel offended, it is the first step in debugging. Check if the function is called at all. You could also use the `debugger;` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **[.is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/)** with **[:empty](http://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/)** selector as well as using **[keyup](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/)** event to have live update when you're typing text inside your input:

```
$('#visitID').on('change keyup', function () {
    if ($(this).is(':empty')) {
        $("#saveandclosebutton").hide();
    } else {
        $("#saveandclosebutton").show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [.toggle( showOrHide )](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/#toggle-showOrHide)

```
$('#visitID').on('change keyup', function () {
    $("#saveandclosebutton").toggle(this.value.length == 0);
});
```

Comment: I tried your code, but nothing changes, Still the saveandclosebutton always appears

Comment: @user2226785 can u make a fiddle .

Answer (score 0):

Try Keyup. Change it to:

```
$('#visitID').keyup(function () {
        var len = $('#visitID').val().length;
        if ( len == 0)
            $("#saveandclosebutton").hide();
        else
            $("#saveandclosebutton").show();
    });
```